# How to stop an ADF pipeline after a particular number of hours?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline with a for each loop on files and performing some activity that should only run for the downtime hours. I am starting it using a trigger and want it to gracefully exit execution after 2 hours, whether it is done looping through all files or not.

Is there a way to configure it in ADF?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the `Until` activity. Inside the loop, you can check something (maybe the time via a web service or a database call) and make it false when the loop should exit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity

Comment: Yes I'm also checking this. So when the until activity stops if the condition is met- does the foreach loop fail or continue to run? What will be the status.

Comment: I suggest you read the linked documentation. Basically it just stops doing thing inside the `Until` and goes on to the next step. You need to put your work inside the `Until`, _not_ inside a `foreach`

Comment: Yes I tried that but ADF is giving bad request error in this case while running. I dont think it is permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way - I used 2 variable at start of the main pipeline :

1. to set start time in utc
2. to set starttime+duration using addtime()

Flow is like this:

1.Set the original time variable as start time of pipeline using utcnow()
2.Set add time using addtime() to last time value till it can execute
3.Set the boolean variable 'state' to true or false comparing if starttime is less than addtime

4.For loop--> 1st run
(
If activity to check 'state' variable
(
True- execute the flow
False-do nothing
)
-->set the original time variable again -->compare with last time and set state to updated value
)
2nd run ....
3rd run..

when 'state' is false
If will run till for each values are exhausted doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a separate pipeline which contains a wait activity(2hr) followed by a web activity.

The web activity can call the data factory api to send a cancel run request.
Refer :
[How-to-cancel-a-pipeline-run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/cancel)

Creating the web activity by referring the [web-activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) and preferably using msi as the authentication.

Another method is using logic app, it already builtin tasks to create a pipeline trigger, cancel it etc.

Comment: But it will just cancel the step which is running at that time. I would like it to not take the next loop item if time is going to be up ,for eg execute one flow of the loop completely before starting the next and not start with next item if time is almost up and it wont be able to finish it completely.

Comment: @Sakhi, Is your for each in sequential or allows parallel run of the copy activities?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is **checking the time difference in each iteration in an if activity** and if it's True, then call the web activity to cancel the pipeline using the REST API.

Before the pipeline activities, create a set variable activity with `@utcnow()`.

[image]

Inside the ForEach, after your activity use an if activity with the below condition.

```
@equals(div(sub(ticks(utcnow()),ticks(variables('mytime'))),600000000),120)
```

[image]

The above conditon checks the time difference between current time and the `mytime` variable is 2 hours (120 minutes) or not.

If it results `True`, add a web activity in the True activities to cancel the Pipeline run with [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/cancel?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) using current pipeline run id.

You can go through this [blog](https://andyleonard.blog/2020/06/one-way-to-break-out-of-an-azure-data-factory-foreach-activity/) by @[Andy Leonard](https://andyleonard.blog/author/andyleonard/) to know about canceling the current pipeline using web activity inside the ForEach.

Comment: Depending on how graceful the exit needs to be, adding a `fail` activity within the `if` activity would be a way to end the pipeline run without needing to call the REST API. It's still graceful in the sense that it doesn't cause a cancellation or timeout in the middle of a loop iteration.

Comment: yeah, in general adding fail activity inside if should stop the loop. But that's not in the case of ADF as these do not a break. ADF loops won't stop until the last iteration, so that's the reason for using the REST API.

Comment: That's a good point. It would cause every remaining iteration to fail without performing any other activities, which might be alright depending on how many iterations are remaining. Unless parallel execution is required, I feel refactoring to an `Until` activity would be a cleaner way to handle it.

Comment: yeah, I agree with you, until can be a better option here because of condition checking.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula we can use addtime() to add min,sec,hours to the current time and compare using less,greater,equal in the expressions instead of using ticks-@equals(div(sub(ticks(utcnow()),ticks(variables('mytime'))),600000000),120). I checked it works.