# Azure Data Factory performance issue or getting stuck

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am running an web activity that reads data from Sharepoint (and then writes aggregated list to the sql db, but it is irrelevant here)
The data comes in pages, each request to sharepoint api, returns 100 records, and there is a __Next field pointing to the next request url, that I am catching.
I am calculating the number of pages (correctly) - 89 of them.  Everything works correctly if I set my loop range from 1..3 or 1..5 even. (that is as if I had only 3 or 5 pages)
However, since the pages are actually - 89 of them, My actual loop controlling expression is

```
@range(1, 
int(variables('varNumberOfPages'))
)
```

Inside of a loop, I run activity to get the record for a current batch, update a variable holding the URL to the next one (__Next from the response) and accumulating the current response into another variable holding the final response (This works correctly, I tested.)

The problem is that for more pages (above 10, I think) my datafactory starts to be stuck ..it seemes that the pipeline runs forever.
The page either looks like this
[image]

or it actually shows a few completed iterations (with everything green, success) and not moving further.
[image]

Please, help me understand how to fix it.  As another FYI:  I am working out of the Dev environment, out of git branch, it is not (yet) the published data factory.  If it matters, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that for more pages (above 10, I think) my datafactory starts to be stuck ..it seemes that the pipeline runs forever.

**AFAIK** and based on the information that you have provided, there is nothing wrong with your pipeline.

The **ForEach will only stop after all iterations of your loop**. It is in **In Progress** state because it has **89** iterations. If you look at the **duration of every iteration** in your pipeline output, then you can understand why it is on In Progress state.

But this also depends on the size of the data in every iteration.

For Example, I have set my ForEach for 50 iterations and using a set variable activity inside it.

You can see, it got completed in 31 seconds as it took less time for my iterations.

[image]

> The page either looks like this

If your output pane getting stuck, you can watch the same activity runs in Monitor pipeline runs-> debug runs -> pipeline.

So, your pipeline didn't stuck. The ForEach is executing all iterations in a sequential manner and it will took time based on the size of the data.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the concept.   So, are you saying, that if I see a behavior like this, it is normal, and if it is not acceptable then maybe ADF itself or a particular approach is not the way to solve the problem ?  I can't control the size of the data ...  I can attempt to use odata filter queries to reduce the fields I am selecting.  Would this help ?

Comment: yeah, if you think the size is more, then using filters before entering the loop might be the better option. and If in any case you don't want to run the pipeline more than a certain time, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425589/how-to-stop-an-adf-pipeline-after-a-particular-number-of-hours/76429254#76429254